# Disable mouse events on NSSplitView

Tags: macos, cocoa

Could anyone can disable or prevent mouse cursor changed when move mouse to divider of `NSSplitView` ?

I have a `NSWindow` with `splitView` inside, then I try to add a `NSView/NSButton` to window's `contentView` to prevent mouse events. What I gain is prevent mouse click, but I need to prevent the mouse cursor changed when I move mouse to `splitView's divider` below.

So what I try to do is:

- Add a view on top to prevent user click on splitView and mouse cursor does not changed.
- Like Sparrow app when Ads shown.

Any kind of hint, help, experience is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your NSSplitView you could add:

```
[self addCursorRect:[self bounds] cursor:[NSCursor whateverCursorYouWant]];
```

Have a look at Apple's sample code [DragItemAround](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/DragItemAround/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003900)